# Звідки звук «н» ві відмінках «стати» або куди зникло «ну» в «станути»?

Tags: дієслова, морфологія

Дїйослова на *~т-а-ти* завичай мають таку структуру:

| Особа | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -**ю** *вітаю*, *маю* | -**єм(o)** *вітаєм(о), маєм(о)* |
| 2 | -**єш** *вітаєш*, *маєш* | -**єте** *вітаєте, маєте* |
| 3 | -**є** *вітає*, *має* | -**ють** *вітають, мають* |

Тобто така собі звична перша дїйовідміна. Однак в дїйослові *стати* замість **й** — ***н***, що вже маїть поведїнку як дїйослова з наростком *ну*, наприклад *та-ну-ти*:

| Особа | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -**ну** *тану, стану* | -**нем(о)** *танем(о), станем(о)* |
| 2 | -**неш** *танеш, станеш* | -**нете** *танете, станете* |
| 3 | -**не** *тане, стане* | -**нуть** *тануть, стануть* |

Тож… куди ся дїв наросток *ну* в *стати*, якщо він там був? З того що пригадаю чи бачу, подібну проблему маїть дїйослово [*дїти*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8#335757), де [*я*] *дїну*.

Answer (score 4):

Це запитання торкається морфології суфіксів, багатством яких слов'янські мови відомі. Боюся, що повноцінна відповідь повинна спиратися на порівняльний аналіз слов'янських мов, а також на історичні корені, які простягаються з часів санскриту.

Суфікс `-ну-` (*танути*) позначає перфектний аспект (perfective), або початок дії, або явище перетворення, подібного до [Inchoative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoative_verb).

Зауважте, слова у запитанні мають також форму з суфіксом `-ва-`, і він пов'язаний з суфіксом `-ну-`.
Суфікс `-ва-` (*давати, ставати*) позначає недоконаний (imperfective) або ітеративний (iterative/frequentative) аспект: дія не завершилася або відбувається повторно.

Розлога цитата з джерела (підкреслено мною):

> In Slavic the the stems *dad-* and *ded-* are reduplicative by origin and primordially denoted Aoristic or perfective aspect, as well as punctual or time-pointed action (see 1.2.). The reduplication did not evolved as a systematic morphologic means aspect and manner in Slavic, but some other morphologic means took place here, esp. prefixes and suppletive perfective stems. One of the means is the nasal affix `[-n/nu-]` that **denotes an
> initiating action**. This affix forms the so called **verba incohativa/inchoativa** in Slavic and it is akin and historically connected to the respective affix in Greek, that forms the so called **nu-verbs**, and probably to the verbs of Sanskrit Sunvaadi class (e.g. *su-*, *sunu- /suno-*). […]
>
> Reduplication in Slavic has to **emphasize a punctual/perfective action**. The Aorist Tense forms are here in place of the Perfect Tense, as the old IE reduplicative Perfect Tense did not evolve in the respective Slavic Perfect tense. Mixing of the rudimentary reduplicative forms with other morphological means of time-pointed or punctual action, i.e. with `[-nu-]` forms) in Slavic, reminds us of the Greek merger of reduplicative Present forms with inchoative *-sk-* form

> For marking the imperfective aspect and iterative/frequentative manner of action, Slavic languages have other morphological means, i.e. affix `[-ja-]` or `[-va-]` or alternation of the two morphs […]

#### Джерело

- Svetislav Kostić: [Grammatical Reduplication In Indic And Slavic](https://www.phil.muni.cz/linguistica/art/kostic/kos-001.pdf) (2007)

Answer (score 2):

До попередньої відповіді додам, що питання загалом не зовсім коректне, бо між формами інфінітиву та особових дієслів немає прямого зв'язку (система дієвідмін є результатом пізньої уніфікації). Щоб отримати повну відповідь треба читати книги під назвою "***[Історична граматика української мови](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)***" та "***[Історична морфологія української мови](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)***".
*Як приклад:*

[image: Л. П. ПАВЛЕНКО Історична граматика української мови]

Comment: Дјакују, ознајму сја з матеріјалами.